# How to show dialog when user is offline and dismiss it when connected to internet using StreamBuilder flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

I tried to build it and searched for it a lot but I got an error

Also, when I go back to the internet, the application does not save the state, and it works from the first screen, which is the main splash.

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
    builder: (ctx, snapConnectivity) {
      final theme = AlmaddTheme.light();
      var result = snapConnectivity.data;

      if (snapConnectivity == null) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      switch (result) {
        case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: theme,
            supportedLocales: ctx.supportedLocales,
            localizationsDelegates: ctx.localizationDelegates,
            locale: ctx.locale,
            home: const MainSplashScreen(),
          );
        case ConnectivityResult.none:
        default:
          return
              CustomerDialog.customerDialog(ctx,
                content: const Text('No Internet'),
                barrierDismissible: false);
      }
    });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'r Material Ancestor are only set to MainSplashScreen, try to wrap your dialog widget inside material widget to

Comment: I did this but it didn't save the state, so how do I save the state?
I mean, for example, in the tenth screen, if the Internet disconnects, it creates the dialog, and if it connects to the Internet, it dismisses the dialog and remains in the same screen.!

Comment: Maybe can you just show the MainSplashScreen, and add the stream builder on it to show dialog when connection lost? With dismiss disabled

Answer (score 0):

I have written a package exclusively for this scenario.

[flutter_no_internet_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_no_internet_widget)

You don't have to worry about the StreamBuilders or the state management.

Example:

```
InternetWidget(
 online: Text('Online'),
 offline: Text('Offline),
);
```

According to the network state, the appropriate widgets will be displayed. If you have an active internet connection an online widget will be displayed.

All the heavyweight is done by the package and all you have to do is provide online and offline widgets. Optionally you can provide a loading widget and lookup URL.

I may haven't answered what you have asked but I'm sharing a package that will help you reduce the workload and achieve your result faster.

[image: flutter_no_internet_widget-video-example]